# I want to fully override eslint rules on folder level

Tags: eslint, eslintrc, eslint-config-airbnb, babel-eslint

on my project I have some eslint rules defined inside eslintrc.json . this is for frontend files . but what I am trying to do is that , I need to defined another eslintrc.json for backendfiles ( folder level) . for example I have controllers folder and I want to override frontend rules fully .

this is working ( but it's also using old frontend rules ) .

is there way to override fully my previous eslintrc.json ? and setup new rules on controllers level?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe, There is some property that you can define in your controller's folder eslint file.